# The SingleChildScrollView is not scrollable

Tags: flutter

This widget renders with no errors except it is not scrollable

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Row(
                children: const [
                    Expanded(child: Text('text'),),
                    Expanded(child: Text('text'),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        RapportList(), // this is not scrollable
      ],
    ),
),
```

Where `RapportList()` is a stateful widget which builds a

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: _rapports.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
        ...
```

I tried to wrap the `ListView.builder` with `SingleChildScrollView` but with no result. It is still not scrollable.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think you just need to add:

```dart
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

to your `RapportList()`.

Here is the code I tested:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Row(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Expanded(child: Text('text'),),
                      Expanded(child: Text('text'),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            ListView.builder( //<--RapportList().
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //<--here
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return ListTile(
                  title: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("ListTile with index ${index}")
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this way, `RapportList()` will not be scrollable and when you
try to 'scroll' one of its elements, you will scroll the entire `SingleChildScrollView();`.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Wrap it with an `Expanded` widget: Sometimes, a `SingleChildScrollView` widget might not be scrollable if it doesn't have enough space to expand. You can try wrapping it with an `Expanded` widget to give it more space to expand vertically. For example:

```dart
Expanded(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: // your code 
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(body:  SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Row(
                children: const <Widget>[
                    Expanded(child: Text('text'),),
                    Expanded(child: Text('text'),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 6000,),
        Text("...."),
        Container(
        ),
      ],
    ),
)
    );  
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and explain why your solution should work?